# Add ProfilePictureView to each row in a ListView

Tags: android, facebook, android-listview

I am displaying a custom `ListView` which contains a `ProfilePictureView` in each row. I wish to grab the user's profile picture from Facebook to display it. However, the default Facebook profile picture shows up only. I think the error is occurring because I am not calling `findViewById` on the XML element, however I cannot figure out how to do this.

Java code for each row

```
public class ChannelRow { 

private ProfilePictureView profilePic;
private String userName;
private String channelName;
private String publisherToken;
private String sessionID;

public ChannelRow(String userName, String channelName, String publisherToken, String sessionID,
                  String profilePicId, Context context){
    this.profilePic = new ProfilePictureView(context);
    this.userName = userName;
    this.channelName = channelName;
    this.publisherToken = publisherToken;
    this.sessionID = sessionID;
    profilePic.setProfileId(profilePicId);
...
}
```

Here in the activity, I grab the user's information from each ParseObject and set it in the ChannelRow

```
    private void createSessionsList(ArrayList<ParseObject> objects) {
    ArrayList<ChannelRow> channels = new ArrayList<>();
    ChannelRow newRow;

    for (ParseObject o : objects) {
        newRow = new ChannelRow((String) o.get("hostName"), (String) o.get("chatTitle"),
                (String) o.get("publisherToken"), (String) o.get("sessionID"),
                (String) o.get("facebookId"), getApplicationContext());
        channels.add(newRow);
    }

    channelData = channels.toArray(new ChannelRow[channels.size()]);
    adapter = new ChannelAdapter(this, R.layout.channel_row, channelData);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    channelListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Here is the XML code for each row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
    android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
....
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the adapter for the ListView

```
    private Context context;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ChannelRow[] data;

public ChannelAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ChannelRow[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ChannelRowHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ChannelRowHolder();
        holder.userName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.userNameTextView);
        holder.channelName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.channelNameTextView);
        holder.profilePic = (ProfilePictureView) row.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ChannelRowHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    ChannelRow channelRow = data[position];
    holder.userName.setText(channelRow.getUserName());
    holder.channelName.setText(channelRow.getChannelName());
    holder.profilePic.setProfileId(channelRow.getProfileId());

    return row;
}

static class ChannelRowHolder
{
    ProfilePictureView profilePic;
    TextView userName;
    TextView channelName;
}

    @Override
public int getCount(){
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public ChannelRow getItem(int pos){
    return data[pos];
}
```

Comment: did you override the getCount and getItem method on the adapter?

Comment: No I didn't override either.

Comment: You'll need to in order to bien your data. In your getItem method add: return data.get(position) and in your getCount add: data.size() and let me know

Comment: I did that and it did not work. Updated the code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to post your `ChannelAdapter` code here for precise answer, but as far as I understand, you're trying to instantiate `ProfilePictureView` in your `ChannelRow` class, whereas it should be done in `ChannelAdapter` class. This way you can call `findViewById()` in adapter and do whatever you want with `ProfilePicutreView`.

**EDIT**

Try to delete `profilePic` field from `ChannelRow` class, I think it might be causing all kinds of trouble. Also could you post logcat output with the stacktrace of exception?

Comment: I am not getting an exception. The profile pictures are just not getting updated, so it is showing the default ones.

Comment: Sorry for some precautions: you sure you do save `profileId` field in `ChannelRow` class and then retrieve it in `ChannelAdapter` class?

Comment: wow you have it with that last comment. I was accidentally using the setter instead of setting the local variable.